# How can I put a old version of my project as master (current working version)?

Tags: git, github, command-line

I've removed all folders/files on my local and then committed it, and then push it. So currently, my master branch on bitbucket is empty. Now I need to set 2 version ago as the master branch. How can I do that?

I can open 2 version ago like this:

```
$ git checkout {token}
```

But in this case, the path looks like this: `~/Desktop/repo ({token})` ..! Well I don't want that, I want the whole value of 2 version ago be copy in master branch. How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `I need to set 2 version ago as the master branch`? Do you simply want master to be at that commit (with all it's history?) or do you want the files that are at that commit as a new commit on your empty bitbucket branch (with no history)? Or do you mean something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Are you mostly concerned about how to update the server, rather than what's local?  If so, your easiest solution might simply be to push that specific branch as the remote master branch.

```
$ git push -f origin {token}:master
```

That says to push to `origin` the `{token}` that you desired, and update the remote `master` branch to be that specific commit, changing history if need be.

You can then re-clone your workspace for a "fresh start".

(There are many ways to achieve this, including with much more git sophistication, but I think the above is your most straight-forward and easy-to-understand solution)

Comment: As far as I know, this command will remove all old commits .. Am I right?

Comment: If the "old commits" are no longer referenced by any branch, they will be eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you want a new commit on top of your previous ones, having the content of some previous commit?

If so, I'd do this:

```
# create branch based on some old commit
git checkout -b merge-to-old-commit token

# do a simple change, just to get a new commit with a message
# then commit it
git commit -m "pulled foo back from previous commit for merging into HEAD."

# and merge that to your master/HEAD
git checkout master
git merge --no-commit merge-to-old-commit
```